# Counting occurrences in array java

Tags: java, arrays, count, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to compute the occurrences of each number in a Java array (like 1=?, 2=?, 3=?). How can my array store more than 10 value?

```
int [] arryNum = new int[]{4,4,4,3,4,5,4,3,4,4,4,5,4,5,5,5,4,3,2,15,4,3,4,6,4,3,4,5,4,2,4,5,4,3,2,5,4,3,5,4,0,4,3,4,5,4,3,0,4,5,4,3,5,4,2,3,2,3,4};
     int[] counter = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < arryNum.length; i++) {
        counter[arryNum[i] ]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < counter.length; i++){
        System.out.println((i + 1) + ":" + counter[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Use a `Map<Integer, Integer>` with the key being the number and the value being the frequency/counter.

Comment: erm... sry @Thomas i am very new in java , may i know how to use the Map<Integer, Integer> to store my value based on my question ?

Comment: Take a look into the [Map Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).  Map itself is an interface, so you can't directly create an instance of it, but you can create an instance of a subclass; IE: `Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();`.  From there, you can use the `put(K,V)`, `get(K)`, and `containsKey(K)` methods to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] arryNum = new int[] { 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 15, 4,
            3, 4, 6, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 2, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 0, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 0, 4,
            5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4 };
    Map<Integer, Integer> lookup = new HashMap<>();
    for (int key : arryNum) {
        if(lookup.containsKey(key)) {
            lookup.put(key, lookup.get(key) + 1);
        } else {
            lookup.put(key, 1);
        }
    }

    for (Integer keys : lookup.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(keys + " Found " + lookup.get(keys) + " Times");
    }

}
```

Comment: I was actually sondering to downvote your answer, as you dont have a single line of explanation there ... but heck. Everyone starts ... but keep in mind: a **good** answer is more than just dropping some working code!

Answer (score 3):

You could write it in a more succint way with java 8 streams:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
Arrays.stream(arryNum).forEach(x -> map.put(x , map.computeIfAbsent(x, s -> 0) + 1));
System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: Hint : for a beginner... Streams are most likely overkill.

Comment: yes, for a beginner your solution is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.

First you need that Map to count your things:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> countsByNumbers = new HashMap<>();
```

Then you iterate your numbers; best using for-each:

```
for (int number : arryNum) {
  if (countsByNumbers.containsKey(number)) {
    int newCount = countsByNumbers.get(number) +1;
    countsByNumbers.put(number, newCount);
  } else {
    countsByNumbers.put(number, 1);
  }
```

Some notes:

1. Be aware that Maps, as any kind of Java Collection class only deals with **reference** types; therefore it is declared to use Integer, and not the primitive type *int*!
2. The compiler does some magic to turn the *int* values from your array into *Integer* objects under the cover
3. Note that *[Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)* is an interface, but that we have to instantiate a concrete class, in this case we simply use *HashMap*

Comment: Good solution, but you should use containsKey(), contains() does not exist for Map.

Comment: Thanks... Fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Considering the array contains String values, put the String into HashMap.
Before inserting each String, check if a key exists for it in the map already
If yes - take the default value for that key, which is 1, and increment it by 1 and insert again.
If no - simply add the new key with default value 1
Final map will give "String":Number of occurences of string.

```
public Map<String, Integer> wordCount(String[] strings) {
  Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap();
  for(String s : strings){
    if(map.containsKey(s)){
      map.put(s, map.get(s)+1);
    }
    else
    map.put(s, 1);
  }
  return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

package com.report.automation;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Frequency {
public static void main(String[] args){

```
    String value[] = {"Mukesh","Mukesh","Sasi","Senthil","Mukesh","Mukesh"};
    String match = "Mukesh";
     int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
    if (match.equals(value[j])) {       
       
        count++;                
        
    }       
    }
    System.out.println(count);
    
}
}
```